# Q-Q Plot side by side and qqline

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I am trying to graph two differente qq plots into a single plot so that it's easier to compare. I have used the `grid.arrange` function previously for other simpler plots but I'm getting an error with qq plots.
I would like it so that both graphs are side by side.

This is my code if it helps:

`qqplotAmericas <- qqplot(AmericasLifeExp$lifeExp,AmericasLifeExp$year, xlab = "Life expectancy", ylab = "Year", main = "Q-Q Plot Americas")`

[image: QQ Plot Number 1]

`qqplotEurope <- qqplot(EuropeLifeExp$lifeExp,EuropeLifeExp$year, xlab = "Life expectancy", ylab = "Year", main = "Q-Q Plot Europe")`

[image: QQ Plot Number 2]

These graphs would signify that the the data does not have a normal distribution as it's qq plot does not follow a normal distribution. If anyone knows how to use the `qqline` function properly for my two graphs, could you please share some info on how it would be done.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`grid.arrange()` works for plots using *grid graphics*, e.g. plots produced by the `lattice` or `ggplot2` packages.

`qqplot()` uses *base graphics*, so you need to use `par(mfrow(...))` (or `par(mfcol(...))` or `layout()`) to set up the plot arrangement. You didn't give a reproducible example, but here's one ...

If you want to make Q-Q plots in a grid-graphics framework you could try `?lattice::qqmath` (see the examples for an example of how to add the Q-Q reference line) or `?ggplot2::geom_qq()` (and see also `geom_qq_line()`).

```r
par(mfrow=c(1,2))  ## one row, two columns
qqplot(qnorm(ppoints(50)),USArrests[,"Murder"])
qqline(USArrests[,"Murder"])
qqplot(qnorm(ppoints(50)),USArrests[,"Assault"])
qqline(USArrests[,"Assault"])
```

[image]